# RabbitMQ: Ack vs NoAck

Tags: c#, queue, rabbitmq

Currently I am testing RabbitMQ. We want run our consumers with acknowledgements (manual). However setting noAck to false makes a channel synchronous when queuing and decreases the performance from 20000 messages consumed per second to 2 messages consumed per second. I increased the prefetch to 20 however that only gave me 20 messages per second.

**Code with noAck=true**

```
class Program
{
    private static IEnumerable<int> Counter()
    {

        int i = 1;
        while (!_isStopping)
            yield return i;

        _isStopped = true;
    }

    private static volatile bool _isStopped;
    private static volatile bool _isStopping;

    private static string _queueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"];
    private static string _hostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"];
    private static bool _isPersistent = false;

    public static void Main()
    {

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = _hostName };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {


                //channel.ConfirmSelect();
                channel.QueueDeclare(_queueName, _isPersistent,false, false, null);
                channel.BasicQos(0, 20, false);


                QueueingBasicConsumer consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);


                channel.BasicConsume(_queueName,true, consumer);

                Task run = new Task(() =>
                {

                    Parallel.ForEach(Counter(), c =>
                    {
                        BasicDeliverEventArgs args = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

                    });

                });


                run.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();

                _isStopping = true;

                while (!_isStopped)
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Code with noAck=false**

```
class Program
{
    private static IEnumerable<int> Counter()
    {

        int i = 1;
        while (!_isStopping)
            yield return i;

        _isStopped = true;
    }

    private static volatile bool _isStopped;
    private static volatile bool _isStopping;

    private static string _queueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"];
    private static string _hostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"];
    private static bool _isPersistent = false;

    public static void Main()
    {

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = _hostName };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {


                //channel.ConfirmSelect();
                channel.QueueDeclare(_queueName, _isPersistent,false, false, null);
                channel.BasicQos(0, 20, false);


                QueueingBasicConsumer consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);


                channel.BasicConsume(_queueName,false, consumer);

                Task run = new Task(() =>
                {

                    Parallel.ForEach(Counter(), c =>
                    {
                        BasicDeliverEventArgs args = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
                        channel.BasicAck(args.DeliveryTag, false);


                    });

                });


                run.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();

                _isStopping = true;

                while (!_isStopped)
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I know that creating multiple channels will probably increase performance, but I don't think creating thousands of channels is a good idea. Why does enabling ack have such horrible results and how do I remedy it?

Answer (score 0):

In short it seems like some odd behavior of ack and parallelization on a single channel. If the Parallel for is changed to be a normal for loop then the performance is greatly increased. I suspect that the most of the threads enter a waiting state as it cannot process the next message before the ack is sent.

According to some on the google group for RabbitMq channels should not be shared between threads.